# ko binding even if button is not clicked

Tags: knockout.js

I have the below code for some reason even before the button is clicked the binding takes place.  Basically I want to show the table after the button is clicked but it binds as soon as the page is loaded. What am I doing wrong here?

JS Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 ShowHideDiv=ko.observable(false);
 function GetResults() {
    alert("test");  //<-- both alerts show as soon as the page loads
    self.ShowHideDiv(true);
    alert(ShowHideDiv()); 
 }

  $(document).ready(function () {
     ko.applyBindings(new GetResults());
  });
</script>
```

The HTML

```
<input type="button"  id="btnSearch" value="Search" style="margin-left:60px;margin-top:20px" tabindex="8" data-bind="click: GetResults" />


<div id="SearchResult" data-bind="visible: ShowHideDiv">
    <table width="100%" id="tblSearchResults">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Child Name</th>
            <th>Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
     <!-- to bind results here -->
    </tbody>

    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are invoking `GetResults` as an object constructor. All lines of code will fire at construction time (`new GetResults()`).

Unless you're doing something reasonably sophisticated that we can't see here, using the `new` keyword to create the viewmodel is over-complicating things. Try something like this:

```
var vm = {
    showResults: ko.observable(false),
    toggleShowResults: function() {
        vm.showResults(!vm.showResults());
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Bound to:

```
<input type="button" data-bind="click: toggleShowResults" />

<div data-bind="visible: showResults">
  <!-- snip -->
</div>
```

Comment: Will try that.  I realized that I actually did not have a viewmodel, my stupidity :(.  Will try you way.  Oh and should I add the bindings in the document ready?